# get information in database and insert into session codeigniter

Tags: php, database, codeigniter, session

i am new to codeigniter and using session. i am having a problem in inserting individual data in session.

Model:

```
function get_user_info() {
    $user_email = $this->input->post('signin-email');
    $this->db->select('acct_id, acct_fname, acct_lname, acct_mname');
    $this->db->where('email', $user_email);
    $query = $this->db->get('account');

    return $query->result_array();
}
```

Controller:

```
public function LoginValidation(){
    $this->load->library('form_validation');

    $this->form_validation->set_rules('email', 'Email', 'required|trim|xss_clean|callback_validate_credentials');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'Password', 'required|trim|md5');
    $this->load->model('users_model');
    if($this->form_validation->run()){
        $data = array(
            'email' => $this->input->post('signin-email'),
            'is_logged_in' => 1,
            'user_info' => $this->users_model->get_user_info($query->acct_type)
        );
        $this->session->set_userdata($data);

        redirect('home');
    } 
}
```

this is the row and i want it to put in session individually:

[image]

it always appear like this:

[image]

how can i make it like this:

```
[acct_id] => 1
[acct_fname] => Sgt
[acct_lname] => Condoriano
[acct_mname] => T
```

Comment: not clear what do u want?

Comment: Instead of using `result_array()` in your model, try and use `row_array()`

Comment: check this line of code `$this->users_model->get_user_info($query->acct_type)` some thing wrong here you do

Comment: @Vicky i want to look like this [user_data] => 
   Array
(
    [email] => qwe@qwe.com
    [is_logged_in] => 1
    [acct_id] => 1
    [acct_fname] => Sgt
    [acct_lname] => Condoriano
    [acct_mname] => T
  
)

Comment: @Craig then how can i ouput it like this ^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Model

```
function get_user_info() {
    $user_email = $this->input->post('signin-email');
    $this->db->select('acct_id, acct_fname, acct_lname, acct_mname');
    $this->db->where('email', $user_email);
    $query = $this->db->get('account');

    return $query->row_array(); // changed to row array
}
```

In Controller

```
$user_info = $this->users_model->get_user_info(); // method does not have any arg
$data = array(
            'email' => $this->input->post('signin-email'),
            'is_logged_in' => 1,
            'user_info' => $user_info
        );
$this->session->set_userdata($data);
/* try this for adding as direct index */
$this->session->set_userdata($user_info);
var_dump( this->session->userdata('acct_id') );
var_dump( this->session->userdata('acct_fname') );
var_dump( this->session->userdata('acct_lname') );
var_dump( this->session->userdata('acct_mname') );
```

Comment: same output [email] => qwe@qwe.com
    [is_logged_in] => 1
    [user_info] => Array
        (
            [acct_id] => 1
            [acct_fname] => Sgt
            [acct_lname] => Condoriano
            [acct_mname] => T
        )

)

Comment: Answer updated. And it cant be same output as result_array return multiple records in multidimensional array and row_array return single row .

Comment: i removed the 'user_info' => $user_info line to make it not redundant and thanks my problem now is resolved [link](http://prntscr.com/7hxqdk)

Answer (score 0):

Transform this

```
function get_user_info() {
    $user_email = $this->input->post('signin-email');
    $this->db->select('acct_id, acct_fname, acct_lname, acct_mname');
    $this->db->where('email', $user_email);
    $query = $this->db->get('account');

    return $query->result_array();
}
```

into this

```
function get_user_info() {
    $user_email = $this->input->post('signin-email');
    $this->db->select('acct_id, acct_fname, acct_lname, acct_mname');
    $this->db->where('email', $user_email);
    $query = $this->db->get('account');

    $result = $query->result_array();
    return reset($result);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

do it something like below

```
$sess_array = array(
                    'acct_id' => 1,
                    'email' => qwe@qwe.com,
                    .....
                );
$this->session->set_userdata('user_data', $sess_array);
```

Answer (score 0):

if you are retriving only one row then ,
just change :

```
return $query->result_array();
```

to

```
return $query->row_array();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

**MODEL**

```
function get_user_info() {
    $user_email = $this->input->post('signin-email');
    $this->db->select('acct_id, acct_fname, acct_lname, acct_mname');
    $this->db->where('email', $user_email);
    $query = $this->db->get('account');

    return $query->first_row('array'); //this is use when you only want to retrieve a single user and use result_array() for more users to be retrieve.
}
```

**CONTROLLER**

```
public function LoginValidation(){
    $this->load->library('form_validation');
    $this->load->helper(array('form','url')); //load if not yet loaded in autoload.php

    $this->form_validation->set_rules('email', 'Email', 'required|trim|xss_clean|callback_validate_credentials');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'Password', 'required|trim|md5');
    if($this->form_validation->run() == false){
       $this->load->view('path'); //page you want to be view if validation is false
    }else {
      $input = $this->input->post();
      $user_info = $this->users_model->get_user_info();
      $data = array(
            'email' => $input['signin-email'],
            'is_logged_in' => 1,
            'user_info' => $user_info
        );
        $this->load->model('users_model');
        $this->session->set_userdata($data);

        redirect('home');
    } 
}
```

Hope this helps. ^__^